# Class 'PDO' not found Error in Upload Laravel project on server

Tags: php, laravel, server

I Want to upload laravel Project in Server But I give this Eror
`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PDO' not found in /datas/moallemm/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php`
I Change PHP version But Don't Work me,How I can fix this Error?

Comment: So you uploaded your laravel project to a server and you're getting this error on the new server? Have you run `composer install` on the new server?

Comment: @jay_aye_see_kay I run this Project in Local And Don't get Any Error Bu in server find this,How I Can run `composer install` on server?